# When should I use mounted and created?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hi guys so I'm new to vue and I know the basis even built my own app but I always asked my self when should I use mounted and created. I'm always concerned about optimization and right now I put all my code in created (fetching from API etc) but I was wondering when should I put for example `axios` calls inside mounted or created for optimization purposes etc.

Comment: Neither `created` nor `mounted` do not wait any async calls so there is no difference but if it's important to you to get some data before a component should be mounted then you can do that stuff in `created` hook.

Comment: check [lifecycle diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) for better understanding. no optimization difference is concerned with these two hooks. it is good practice to prepare your data before template compilation into render function and `created` hook is the best place to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `created` unless you need access to the element `this.$el` (or any other element ref) then use `mounted` instead.

There isn't really any optimization improvement using one over the other, as long as you choose a convention and stick to it.

Comment: Well, if you are making requests to a server is more optimal if you use created